# Issues with getting GMailSender to work. Continue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23533439/android-issue-with-getting-gmailsender-to-work

Tags: java, android, gmail, jakarta-mail

I've tried all alternatives, my GMailSender is still not working, could you please help to figure out the issues? Or another way to send an email from gmail is also much appreciated.

I copied all the error below each port that I tried.
Note: The permission is provided in AndroidManifest file. I called the GMailSender from an AsyncTask as well.
Thank you very much,

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private Session session;
    private Multipart _multipart;
    static {
        Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());

    }
    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", mailhost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        //443 doesn't work (Connection refused)
        //465 doesn't work javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        //587,25 doesn't work, javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x83ca3680: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
        props.put("javax.activation.debug", "true");


        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
        session.setDebug(true);
    }
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }
    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body,
                                      String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        System.out.println("Inside GMailSender, sendMail, session: " + session);
        System.out.println("Inside GMailSender, sendMail, session.getProperty(): " + session.getProperty("mail.smtp.port"));
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setDataHandler(handler);
        System.out.println("Inside GMailSender, sendMail, message: " + message);
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
        else
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
        Transport.send(message);
    }

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception
    {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
        private byte[] data;
        private String type;
        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.type = type;
        }
        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }
        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
        public String getContentType() {
            if (type == null)
                return "application/octet-stream";
            else
                return type;
        }
        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }
        public String getName() {
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";
        }
        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");
        }
    }

}
```

THE LOG

```
session: javax.mail.Session@78308db1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.example.testinglib.MyTesting.main(MyTesting.java:48)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1564)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1551)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.ehlo(SMTPTransport.java:935)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:426)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:310)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
    at com.example.testinglib.MyTesting.main(MyTesting.java:43)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a shorter solution:

```
package com.example.mail;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMailTLS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String username = "username@gmail.com";
        final String password = "password";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from-email@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("to-email@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Source: [Sending Email via JavaMail API](https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/)

Hope this Helps! Good Luck!

Comment: Yes, the code in the original post was copied from some very old and obsolete code.  The above is much better, although you can also [get rid of the Authenticator](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).  Finally, make sure you're using the official [JavaMail (Jakarta Mail) for Android](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/Android).  If it still doesn't work, post the [debug output](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/FAQ#debug).

Comment: Gentlemen, thank you but it doesn't work either, I changed the port too, not working. I edited the question to add the log, please help me take a look? Thank you!

Comment: You should enable "Less secure app access" here : https://myaccount.google.com/security?hl=en

Comment: I sure enabled it a long time ago for the user that I am sending email from. I've checked, it is still on.

Comment: Did you use my implementation? Also, sometimes this may occur due to incorrect credentials so make sure that the credentials are in fact correct.

Comment: I did use your code, it doesn't work. What do you mean by credentials? Do you mean the sender's email and password? They are all correct. I've been trying in several ways unsuccessfully.

Comment: After many days, I am able to send email through an gmail account now. Definitely it's helpful to use JavaMail but it has a lot to do with cacert, avg virus blocking, and google account configuration. Thank you all for your time.